# How to convert ppt into pdf using Rmagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Any help please on converting ppt into pdf using Rmagick.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this a couple of years ago and at the the time it was not possible. An alternative would be to use JRuby and the [Apache POI project](http://poi.apache.org/) (doesn't support pptx as far as I can tell) or the commercial [Aspose.Slides](http://www.aspose.com/) product (which does support pptx). In either case, you go from PowerPoint to an image and then build a PDF with the images.